# Split number into the primes inside it

Tags: python, string

So I have a list of numbers that look like "3723311723" and "13617172343". As you can see these numbers can be split into prime numbers e.g "3723311723" could be split into 37, 23, 31 ect. How could I write a python program that takes a number like this as an input and returns a list of the primes inside it (in the order they are found)?

Thanks.

Comment: I should add that I only want to find 2 digit primes

Comment: Is the input format a number or a string?

Comment: Whatever is easier to work with

Comment: Where are you stuck solving this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you know that the numbers are definitely gonna be prime, then you just have to break up the string into substrings of length 2, right?

```
s = "37233141712331719337"
print([int(s[i:i+2]) for i in range(0, len(s), 2)])
```

Output:

```
[37, 23, 31, 41, 71, 23, 31, 71, 93, 37]
```

EDIT:

This does a recursive search to find non-overlapping primes. If there's no valid split, it returns False. The usual caveats of recursion apply: if the input is too long, you'll recurse too deep and the program will blow up. But you can use a stack instead of recursing if that's an issue.

```
def is_prime(n):
    for k in range(2, n):
            if n % k == 0:
                    return False
    return True
def primesplit(s, i=0):
    if i+1 >= len(s):
        return []
    if i+2 <= len(s):
        two_digits = int(s[i:i+2])
        if is_prime(two_digits):
            remaining_digits = primesplit(s, i+2)
            if isinstance(remaining_digits, list):
                return [two_digits] + remaining_digits
    one_digit = int(s[i:i+1])
    if not is_prime(one_digit):
        return False
    remaining_digits = primesplit(s, i+1)
    if isinstance(remaining_digits, list):
        return [one_digit] + remaining_digits
    return False
s = "37233141712331719337"
result = primesplit(s)
print(result)
print("".join(map(str, result)) == s)
```

Output:

```
[37, 23, 31, 41, 71, 23, 31, 7, 19, 3, 37]
True
```

Comment: I should have said 1-2 digit primes, that's my bad. So it could be either starting with 37, or 3 then 7 then 23

Comment: You'll need to describe the problem a biiiit more precisely. Can there be non-primes in the input? What do you do with overlapping primes? For example, "23" can be [23], [2, 3] or [2, 3, 23]. "437" can be [3, 7], [43, 3, 7], or [43, 7].

Comment: So for the number "37233141712331719337" I would want to find all the variations of splitting it into primes if you can split the whole list. So it would return 37 23 31 41 71 23 31 71 19 3 37 or 3 7 23 23 31 41 71 23 31 71 19 3 37 or any other variation where the entire number is used to create the list and every split is prime. Sorry, it's hard for me to describe what I want.

Comment: For overlapping primes maybe it could leave a nested list with the different possibilities? And there could be non-primes like 4, but they will always be followed by something else that could make a 2 digit prime (so if there was a 4, it would be followed by 1, 3, or 7).

Comment: That's tricky, you can end up in a dead end. One option is a recursive search, I'll try to hack something together.

Answer (score 0):

This is what you are looking for:
The loop finds both 1 and 2 digit prime numbers in the order they appear in the original number and there will be no duplicates too.

```
In [126]: n
Out[126]: '37233141712331719337'

In [127]: primes = []
     ...: for i in range(len(n)-1):
     ...:     n1 = int(n[i])
     ...:     n2 = int(n[i:i+2])
     ...:     if isPrime(n1):
     ...:         if n1 not in primes:
     ...:             primes.append(n1)
     ...:     if isPrime(n2):
     ...:         if n2 not in primes:
     ...:             primes.append(n2)
     ...:

In [128]: primes
Out[128]: [3, 37, 7, 2, 23, 31, 1, 41, 17, 71, 19]
```

Comment: If you could use nested lists to show the numbers, so that instead of 3, 37, 7 it would be [37, [3, 7]] that would be exactly what I need.

Answer (score 0):

It's a bit complicated what you are asking for, but here's what I thought you meant:
**Given a number, look for any two digit prime within that number(I assume they ARE allowed to overlap)**
A easy way to do that is like this:

```
def isPrime(number):
    if number>1:
        for i in range(2,number):
            if (number%i)==0:
                return False
        return True
    else:
        return False

    

def getPrimes(number):
    number=str(number)
    retList=[]
    for i in range(len(number)-1):
        temp=int(number[i:i+2])
        if isPrime(temp):
            retList+=[temp]
    return retList
```

This does NOT check for single digit primes, but that could easily be added if you needed it (simply check every digit in the original number if they are prime).

Is this what you wanted?

Answer (score 0):

Here is how you can use the `isprime` method from the [`sympy`](https://www.sympy.org/en/index.html) module, and `zip`:

```
from sympy import isprime

n = "37233141712331719337"
lst = [int(i + j) for i, j in zip(n, n[1:]) if isprime(int(i + j))]
print(lst)
```

Output:

```
[37, 23, 31, 41, 17, 71, 23, 31, 17, 71, 19, 37]
```